# adding two array of numbers together and put it into a new array (C)

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to randomly generate two 30-digits array and add them up. The result has to be put into a separate new array. I am having trouble to add up two numbers together if their sum is bigger than 10. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
int numlist[30],numlist2[30],addnum[60],i,j,k;
srand(time(NULL));


for (i=0;i<30;i++)
{
    numlist[i] = rand()%10;

}

for (j=0;j<30;j++)
{
    numlist2[j]=rand()%10;
}

for (k=0;k<30;k++)
{

    if ((numlist[k]+numlist2[k])<10)
        addnum[k] =  numlist[k]+numlist2[k];
    else
       /*dont know what to do*/



}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to implement a carry register.

Comment: Hint: Result array index should not dependent on the variable looped over the array ( if you wish to keep the result sequentially in the `addnum` ).

Comment: first think what you've to do if the `sum` is not bigger than 10.
you obviously have to put some kind of MARKER there so you can identify later if it was run in case of the ELSE block.

Comment: you guys are nuts. This is just long addition, right? How would you do it on paper? You carry the 1 to the next column. same concept.

Comment: Hello Garr. How do you achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Use a carry register:

```
int carry = 0;
for (k=0;k<30;k++)
{
    int adder = numlist[k]+numlist2[k]+carry;
    carry = adder/10;
    addnum[k] = adder % 10;
}
addnum[k] = carry;
```

Comment: Minor: A complete addition needs to continue with `for (k++;k<60;k++) { addnum[k] = 0; }`

Comment: ah, yes. either that or zero-init the array.

Comment: (technically, adding 2 30 digit numbers will result in at most a 31 digit number)

Comment: True about the sum being 31 significant digits.  As `addnum` has room for 60 digits and there is no variable indicating how many of the digits are considered significant, filling all 60 with something, even with 29 leading 0 is good practice.